# Why there's no error in this code? j is final and static but still accessible using object of class how?

Tags: java, interface

```
interface TempInterface {
    static final int j = 30;
}
class TempClass implements TempInterface {
}
public class Try {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    
        TempClass obj = new TempClass();
        
        System.out.println(obj.j);
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the `static` keyword means that the variable can be accessed by every object of a class. Java forces every variable in an interface to be both static and final, so every object of a class that implements it will be able to access that variable, but not change it.

Answer (score 0):

A static variable is nothing more than a fixed memory location shared by all instances of the class (since it belongs to the class itself). This means that all of the instances can access it since they know its location. Note however that it is usually frowned upon if you access a static field from an instance instead of a class reference.

For further information I suggest you read up on [Oracle's tutorial regarding class variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html). To quote a section:

> Sometimes, you want to have variables that are common to all objects. This is accomplished with the `static` modifier. Fields that have the `static` modifier in their declaration are called *static fields* or *class variables*. They are associated with the class, rather than with any object. Every instance of the class shares a class variable, which is in one fixed location in memory. Any object can change the value of a class variable, but class variables can also be manipulated without creating an instance of the class.

Regarding interfaces, you can think of them as special types of classes, so by implementing an interface you inherit all of its data as well (i.e. static variables).

Answer (score 0):

Static means that you have access without need to create new instance, final means - you can'not change but you may get this.

And I can note what interface variable may be accesed from another package too because it's also implicitly public (as static and final).